# API Call 'tabs.captureVisibleTab' is not supported in Edge

Tags: microsoft-edge, microsoft-edge-extension

I'm using Edge on Windows 10 v1703, build 15063.296.
The documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/extensions/api-support/supported-apis) states, that the API tabs.captureVisibleTab is available.

But when I use it in the background script, I'm getting the following error:

> API Call 'tabs.captureVisibleTab' is not supported in Edge.

The code is:

```
browser.tabs.captureVisibleTab(currentTab.windowId, {format: "png"}, function (data) {});
```

Am I missing something?

### UPDATE:

this is my manifest file (ported from Chrome):

```
{
"author": "Evgeny Suslikov",
"background": {
    "page": "background.html",
    "persistent": true
},
"browser_action": {
    "default_icon": {
        "19": "images/sss_19.png"
    },
    "default_title": "FireShot - Capture page",
    "default_popup": "fsPopup.html"
},
"commands": {
    "last-used-action": {
        "suggested_key": {
            "default": "Ctrl+Shift+Y",
            "mac": "Command+Shift+Y"
        },
        "description": "__MSG_options_label_last_action_hotkey__"
    }
},
"default_locale": "en",
"description": "__MSG_application_description__",
"icons": {
    "16": "images/sss_16.png",
    "32": "images/sss_32.png",
    "48": "images/sss_48.png",
    "128": "images/sss_128.png"
},
"Key": "B5SSrXXpDZAoT8SQ4vAzNeTQ1tBC2Z24nx+hHZXfykmVYfMy5aOwPkf0Hbt7SXlKbprwV0GwrYgCwIDAQAB",
"manifest_version": 2,
"name": "__MSG_application_title__",
"offline_enabled": true,
"optional_permissions": [
    "tabs",
    "<all_urls>",
    "downloads"
],
"options_page": "fsOptions.html",
"permissions": [
    "activeTab",
    "tabs",
    "contextMenus",
    "nativeMessaging"
],
"short_name": "FireShot",
"version": "0.98.92",
"web_accessible_resources": [
    "images/*.gif"
],
"-ms-preload": {
    "backgroundScript": "backgroundScriptsAPIBridge.js",
    "contentScript": "contentScriptsAPIBridge.js"
},

"content_scripts": [{
    "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
    "js": ["scripts/fsUtils.js", "scripts/fsSelection.js", "scripts/fsLinks.js", "scripts/fsContent.js"]
}]
}
```

In my fsBackground.js page I do the call:

```
     browser.tabs.captureVisibleTab(windowId, {format: "png"}, function (data) {});
```

I get the following error: [click to see screenshot...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iELcN.png)

Comment: Could you provide a repro sample containing `manifest.json` and a minimized api call? Please ensure required `permissions` are declared in manifest file.

Comment: Thanks, I've just upated my post with the required information.

Comment: Problem solved - added <all_urls> to the permissions list in manifest.json

Answer (score 1):

That function is supported  [starting from Edge 15](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/tabs/captureVisibleTab). On previous versions it was still unsupported, even though the documentation said differently.

Make sure to download the latest version of [Microsoft Edge Extension Toolkit](https://www.microsoft.com/store/p/microsoft-edge-extension-toolkit/9nblggh4txvb) and to regenerate the bridge files with it.

You can look at the generated backgroundScriptsAPIBridge.js file to see what's changed.

Previous versions (unsupported):

```
captureVisibleTab(windowId, options, callback) {
    bridgeLog.LogUnavailbleApi("tabs.captureVisibleTab");
}
```

New version (supported):

```
captureVisibleTab(windowId, options, callback) {
    bridgeLog.DoActionAndLog(() => {
        myBrowser.tabs.captureVisibleTab.apply(null, arguments);
    }, "tabs.captureVisibleTab");
}
```